# tidyverse , plyr and dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I used to use dplyr everywhere, but have included some plyr functions . To be honest I do not know what the difference is or why things have changed . The same code results in different dataframes depending on whether I have imported plyr or tidyverse .
What I wanted to have is a dataframe named newborn_stat  containing unique pids in each row  and a new c_pos column.

```
raw_file_contents<- data.frame( pid=c(1,2,2,3,3), C_SYMP=c("Y","N","Y","N","N"))
newborn_stat<- raw_file_contents %>%
        group_by(pid) %>%
        summarise(c_pos= any( C_SYMP == "Y", na.rm = TRUE))
```

instead I would get a data frame ,newborn_stat, of 1 rows
with c_pos equal to TRUE.
If I use dplyr::  with the group_by and summarise , I think I get the right answer.
Why does this happen?
I have been using a Rmd notebook, so when I tried to run the previous chunk containing this line, things didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

So I assumed this was due to the functions of `dplyr` and `plyr` working differently. It was a mostly correct assumption as but both `dplyr` and `plyr` has `summarize` functions, while  `dplyr` has `group_by` , but `plyr` doesn't. If you import  `plyr` at a later chunk and then rerun the expression shown in the question, `summarize`  is assumed to be the one from `plyr` namespace. so you are running `dplyr::group_by` + `plyr::summarize` in that expression.

I wish they used a different name for summarize in `plyr`. or keep the same function names throughout , if that makes sense.

Comment: I think you're right with all this. Is there some reason you need {plyr}? It causes a lot of problems if you're using the modern {tidyverse} and is better to avoid ever loading it if you can. Otherwise there's the [{conflicted}](https://github.com/r-lib/conflicted) package which can help resolve these things explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly as you explain in your answer, the issue is the difference in the behavior of `plyr::summarize()` and `dplyr::summarize()`. To make this clear I've just put the results of your example here.

```r
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

data.frame(pid = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
           C_SYMP = c("Y", "N", "Y", "N", "N")) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(pid) %>%
  plyr::summarise(c_pos = any(C_SYMP == "Y", na.rm = TRUE))
#>   c_pos
#> 1  TRUE

data.frame(pid = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
           C_SYMP = c("Y", "N", "Y", "N", "N")) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(pid) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(c_pos = any(C_SYMP == "Y", na.rm = TRUE))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>     pid c_pos
#>   <dbl> <lgl>
#> 1     1 TRUE 
#> 2     2 TRUE 
#> 3     3 FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>