# Why group_by can't be used to calculate averages properly?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data.frame c, it has two columne a and b. I want to group columns a and average columns b.
but it not work well

this is my data.frame and code

```
> c
      a      b
1   Red  60822
2   Red 343855
3  Blue   5510
4  Blue   5633
5   Red    299
6  Blue     42
7  Blue    140
8   Red     29
9  Blue   3935
10  Red   6546
11 Blue     17
12 Blue  26400

> c %>% as_tibble() %>% group_by(a) %>% summarise(dd = mean(b))
     dd
1 37769

> class(c)
[1] "data.frame"

> str(c)
'data.frame':   12 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: chr  "Red" "Red" "Blue" "Blue" ...
 $ b: num  60822 343855 5510 5633 299 ...
```

And Rversion, Dplyr package version:

```
> R.version
               _                                
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32               
arch           x86_64                           
os             mingw32                          
crt            ucrt                             
system         x86_64, mingw32                  
status                                          
major          4                                
minor          2.1                              
year           2022                             
month          06                               
day            23                               
svn rev        82513                            
language       R                                
version.string R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23 ucrt)
nickname       Funny-Looking Kid  
> packageVersion("dplyr")
[1] ‘1.1.3’
```

Comment: This looks like a nameclash with the `plyr` package. Have you loaded the retired `plyr` package as well and did so after loading `dplyr`?

Comment: Side note: you can specify the grouping (`.by = a`) inside `summarise()`: `library(dplyr); cc |> summarise(dd = mean(b), .by = a)`, where `cc` is your `c`.

Comment: @stefan yes, the reason is nameclash, if i run `c %>% as_tibble() %>% dplyr::group_by(a) %>% dplyr::summarise(dd = mean(b))` it will work. thankyou! By the way, how did you discover the problem of nameclash?

Comment: Can't remember when I figured that out. Probably I ran into the same issue once and found a post or comment on SO  about that, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71088054/tidyverse-plyr-and-dplyr